# User can see Oracle tables via ODBC that her account does not have access to

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, security, ms-access, odbc

We have a user whose Oracle account, according to ALL_TAB_PRIVS, has access to tables A, B, and C. However, when the user creates an ODBC and connects to Oracle via Microsoft Access (using her Oracle credentials in the ODBC), she can also view data from D, E, and F. We know that she isn't sharing someone else's credentials because we had her create a new ODBC and a new MS Access database, and the issue is still happening. One of our DBA's ran a query (I don't know which system views or tables) that shows her username as having used MSACCESS.EXE and odbcad32.exe to connect to Oracle, but nothing more specific than that.

This is worrisome. How is ODBC apparently bypassing Oracle security?

EDIT: To clarify, the tables in question are not in the user's schema. We keep many business tables in a particular schema S and then grant users access to just those tables in that schema. Consequently, most of the end users' schemas are empty. Our workflow generally goes like this:
1. User X requests access to tables on S schema.
2. Oracle account X is created on the server.
3. X is granted access to specific S tables.

Comment: Most importantly, are the tables in her schema? Are there any grants on the relevant tables to PUBLIC or roles that the user has granted?

Comment: The tables are in a different schema, schema S. That is not a problem; we use S to store most of the tables we want to grant access to, so most of the end users' schemas are empty because they only use the tables in S. Good point, I'll edit the post to clarify.

Comment: Check the ROLES which has been granted to this user. And check which privileges these roles have. Note, a ROLE may contain other roles which contains additional privileges. You have to check the recursively.

Comment: Check the user doesn't have `SELECT ANY TABLE` granted

Comment: You can turn on auditing for one or several of the tables in question and see if this persons username comes up in the audit log.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the user had been granted other privileges by a different account as well as the one we use, so we were unable to see those privileges in ALL_TAB_PRIVS. We had to look in DBA_TAB_PRIVS, and sure enough, there were the other permissions. Thanks to all for chiming in!